# How to use private method of a constructor in object instance

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have made a constructor function. I am now adding properties and methods to it. Now, I also add a private function named ceta() to it. After, I make an instance (obj1) from constructor function, how can I use private function to object instance (Not, using call, apply, bind).

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script>

function alpha(){
  this.a = 10;
  this.b = 20;
  this.beta = function(){
    this.c = 30; 
    alert (c);
  }
  var ceta = function(){
    alert ("hi!");
  }
}

var obj1 = new alpha;

obj1.beta();// this works
obj1.ceta();// this not 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Private methods can't be used outside the object, that's what makes them private.

Comment: If you want to make it public, assign it to a property. `this.ceta = ceta;`

Comment: JavaScript has no "private method" or "private property", all properties and methods are public.

Comment: What @Barmar said . Not literal private and public access modifiers but the way functional scoping works makes them private or publicly available .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ceta` is in the scope of constructor function `alpha` but **do not** belong to the objects being constructed. It can be used in or taken under closure and returned from `this.beta` function though. Such as;

```
function alpha(){
  this.a = 10;
  this.b = 20;
  this.beta = function(){
    ceta(); // <<-- invoke here for some purpose
    this.c = 30; 
    alert(this.c);
    return ceta; // <<-- or return here
  }
  var ceta = function(){
    alert ("hi!");
  }
}

var obj  = new alpha(),
    ceta = obj.beta(); // alerts twice and obj.c is set to 30
```

But these are mostly useless practices. The main task of `ceta` should be to provide utility services to help the constructor to construct objects.

If you need to access `ceta` from all instances of `alpha` then put it in the prototype of `alpha`.